# Returning variables inside JS / JSON functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, return-value

I'm trying to understand JSON, callbacks, etc within JS.  From the altered example below, you'll see that I'm in a function callback from $.getJSON.  Then, I jump into getSomething() and expect it to alter my result variable.  It alters it within the scope of the function, but not when I jump out of that function.

You'll see from the 2 console.log()'s that the first one displays correct, and the second one doesn't.  I'm sure the answer to my question has to do with returning variables via. callback, but could someone enlighten 
me :)

Thanks!

**CODE:**

```
$.getJSON('/cart.js', function (cart, textStatus) {
  var result = '';
  result += 'Sample Stuff';
  StackOverflow.getSomething(param1, param2, function(a, b) {
    for(j=0; j < b.length; j++) {
      if (b.options[j] != 'Default Title') {
        if (a.options[j].name.indexOf("Color") > -1) {
          result += b.options[j].name;
          console.log(result); // <-- It comes out correct (Sample Stuff + b.options...)
        }
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(result); // <-- It comes out incorrect, just (Sample Stuff)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `StackOverflow.getSomething()` runs an AJAX request? So what is defined inside of it's callback (looping through `a` and `b`) is not executed until the AJAX request is finished. What happens is that `StackOverflow.getSomething` is fired and then `console.log(result)` at the end of your code is executed immediately afterwards. By that time, the callback of `StackOverflow.getSomething` hasn't been run yet, and `result` hasn't been updated yet. Only "Sample stuff" is logged. But when the second console.log is executed in the callback after the  AJAX request (of `getSomething`), `result` is updated and logged "correctly".

In other words, the execution order would be this

1. Set `result` to "Sample stuff"
2. `StackOverflow.getSomething()` fires an AJAX request with an attached callback function
3. `console.log(result)` logs "Sample stuff"
4. The ajax callback finishes and fires its callback function. `result` is updated accordingly by iterating over `a` and `b`
5. The callback function's `console.log(result)` logs the final value of `result`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I think I may have assumed most of that, but still don't know how to go about having the "result" from getSomething() tie into getJSON() so that it happens before the rest of getJSON() is executed.

Comment: If you depend on `result` to be correct for the rest of getJSON to function properly, you'll have to put the rest of the getJSON code into the callback of `StackOverflow.getSomething` :)